# Data Validations in ASP.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in one application with asp.net in MVC. Now I have to provide validations for each and every input. As I am new to MVC and not much idea about how to provide validations. Can anyone help me to get this.

Upload

In the above piece of code accepting maximum date value and minimum data value.
It should accept Min date(issued date) value first and Max date(expiry date) second.but its working reverse now.
Can anyone help me to provide the validations for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can set two way Validation 
one is client side and another is server side

server side validation given below

you can compare the issued date against the current date/time, and also compare the expiry date with the issued date

```
public class MyClass : IValidatableObject
{               
    [Required(ErrorMessage="issued date and time cannot be empty")]
    //validate:Must be greater than current date
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime issuedDateTime { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="expiry date and time cannot be empty")]
    //validate:must be greater than issuedDate
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime expiryDateTime { get; set; }       

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (issuedDateTime < DateTime.Now)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("issued date and time must be greater than current time", new []{"issuedDateTime"}));
        }

        if (expiryDateTime <= issuedDateTime)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("expiryDateTime must be greater that issuedDateTime", new [] {"expiryDateTime"}));
        }

        return results;
    }     
}
```

I hope it will help you .